# Validation not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The html is

```js
$(":input.validate-required").on('keyup', function() {
                $(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                $(this).next('small').addClass('hide');
            });

            $("#room_number").on('keyup', function() {
                if (validateRoomNumber() == false) {
                    $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
                    $("#duplicate_error").removeVlass('hide');
                }

            });


            function validateRoomNumber() {
                var FloorNumber = $("#floor_number").val().trim();
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber.length; i++) {
                    var AssignedFloorNumber = arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber[i];
                    if (AssignedFloorNumber == FloorNumber) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Room Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input id="room_number" name="room_number" type="number" class="form-control validate-required" min="0" value="" />
        <small id="room_number_help" class="text-danger hide">Room Number is Required</small>
        <small id="duplicate_error" class="text-danger hide">Room Number is Already Assigned</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have written below line of code for doing validation in javascript.

Note that the below line is also useful

```
         $(":input.validate-required").on('keyup', function () {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            $(this).next('small').addClass('hide');
        });
```

Now When user enters any already existing number, the duplicate error message does not get displayed.

Note that the arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber contains already existing Room Numbers in database.

Please help!!!

Comment: where is `$("#floor_number")`?

Comment: What does `arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber` looks like?

Comment: please add the field with `id='floor_number'`

Comment: As Sachi Tekina says I think you have to put `$("#room_number")` instead of `$("#floor_number")`

Answer (score 1):

Few quick things, change this to `.nextAll()` so that it targets both:

```
$(this).nextAll('small').addClass('hide');
```

Change the function `validateRoomNumber()` to:

```js
function validateRoomNumber() {
  var FloorNumber = $("#floor_number").val().trim();
  if (arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber.indexOf(FloorNumber) > -1)
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Add another field for `floor_number`:

```
<input id="floor_number" name="floor_number" type="number" class="form-control validate-required" min="0" value="" />
```

In case, if the `room_number` and `floor_number` are the same and it's a typo, then use the following code:

```js
function validateRoomNumber() {
  var FloorNumber = $("#room_number").val().trim();
  if (arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber.indexOf(FloorNumber) > -1)
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check working snippet
there are one typo mistake "removeVlass"

and there is statement $("#floor_number"). No input with "floor_number" id present. so chnaged

```
var FloorNumber = $("#room_number").val().trim();
```

```js
$(":input.validate-required").on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    $(this).next('small').addClass('hide');
});

$("#room_number").on('keyup', function() {
  if (validateRoomNumber() == false) {
      $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
      $("#duplicate_error").removeClass('hide');
  }

});


function validateRoomNumber() {
  var FloorNumber = $("#room_number").val().trim();
  var i;
  var arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber = ["10","20", "30", "40", "50"];
  for (i = 0; i < arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber.length; i++) {
      var AssignedFloorNumber = arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber[i];
      if (AssignedFloorNumber == FloorNumber) {
          return false;
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Room Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input id="room_number" name="room_number" type="number" class="form-control validate-required" min="0" value="" />
        <small id="room_number_help" class="text-danger hide">Room Number is Required</small>
        <small id="duplicate_error" class="text-danger hide">Room Number is Already Assigned</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have altered your code a little

```
            function validateRoomNumber(roomnum)
            {

                for (i = 0; i < arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber.length; i++) {
                    var AssignedFloorNumber = arrayOfAssignedRoomNumber[i];
                    if (AssignedFloorNumber == roomnum) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                $(":input.validate-required").on('keyup', function () {
                    $(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                    $(this).next('small').addClass('hide');
                });

                $("#room_number").on('keyup', function () {
                    if (validateRoomNumber($(this).val()) == false)
                    {
                        $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
                        $("#duplicate_error").removeClass('hide');
                    } else {
                        $("#duplicate_error").addClass('hide');
                    }

                });

            });
```